# Recursive search and replace in word VBA script

Tags: vba, recursion, ms-word

Is it possible to do a recursive search and replace for a specific string in a word VBA script?

Specifically, I would like to replace all instances of " :" with ":".

I have extensively searched, but have not found anything.

I am not asking for a code solution, but a pointer in the right direction or example online would be fantastic.

Comment: Why do you want your search to be **recursive** ? Selection.Find with Replace:=wdReplaceAll is not enough ? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: No, you don't need your search to be recursive. The link above should help you.

Comment: @M.Page Is using Selection.Find with Replace:=wdReplaceAll equivalent to the "Replace All" button within word? If so, would I just run that in a loop instead of making it recursive? I'm not a programmer but hoping I know enough to implement this.

Comment: Yes, Selection.Find with Replace:=wdReplaceAll is equivalent to the "Replace All" button within word. The difference is that if you have 100 documents to process, you can run your macro on each document automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, create a VBA macro like this:

```
Sub rem_space()
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    With myRange.Find
        .Text = " :"
        .Replacement.Text = ":"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
            Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have to run the macro several times, it is probably because you may have several spaces in front of a colon. In this case do: for i = 1 to 10: rem_space: next i (10 is just an example here).

Comment: Use wildcards to find " {1,10}:" and replace it by ":" (don't put the quotation marks in there)

Comment: @bibadia can you give an example?

Comment: The difference is that you need .Text = " {1,10}:" , .Replacement.Text = ":", .MatchWildcards=True